# Enable events in main windows while modal window is active

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, mouseevent

In a WPF window I implemented a component that gives an indication of all active errors in the system.
The component is located in the task bar and

- If one hovers over the component a tool-tip is shown with summary info
- If one clicks on the control, a panel is the activated that is showing a detailed list.

In the application we also use wizards implemented as modal windows.

Now, here's my problem: if a new event occurs in the system during an active wizard, the component in the task bar is updated however I cannot use the hover event to see a summary. Both events (hover and click) are not usable due to the modal dialog that hides the parents message loop.
Is their a way (or what's the best solution/suggestion) to have at least the hover message active while the modal wizard is present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They don't call it "modal" for nothin' :-)

Humor aside, depending on your exact scenario, here's two options and a third option that's a bit more involved and you probably don't need it but it can handle a wider range of scenarios:

**Option 1.** It sounds like you have a normal app that does not show its MainWindow and is using only its taskbar presence. If this is the case then you don't need a dialog at all, simply use the MainWindow itself as the "dialog".

**Option 2.** If you are already using the MainWindow visibly then use a pseudo-modal approach whereby you don't actually use a dialog but all other controls except the control acting as your "dialog" control are hidden/collapsed.

Option 3. Use two separate processes. Basically, this is two separate apps - one is your taskbar component and the other is your main app. Use IPC to link the two - e.g. I have used a Windows pipe for such a thing and it works fine.